# Issues with passing ng-model to custom directive and making it work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel, isolate-scope, angularjs-select

I've created a custom directive that auto-populates a select with a list of countries. The directive has a preselect isolate scope attribute, that if set to true will preselect a country.

`ng-model` is also passed as an isolate scope attribute
The problem is that **`ng-model` won't be set**.

Could anyone give me some pointers on how to make the `<auto-countries>` directive so that I'm able to set `ng-model` ?

here's my directive's code:

```
app.directive('autoCountries', function() {
    return {
        restict: 'E',
        controller: 'CountriesCtrl as ctrl',
        scope: {
            preselect: '=',
            ngModel: '='
        },
        template: [

            '<select ng-if="!preselect" ng-model="ngModel">',
                '<option value="">Select Country</option>',
                '<option ng-repeat="country in ctrl.countries" value={{country.name}}>',
                    '{{country.name}}',
                '</option>',
            '</select>',

            '<select ng-if="preselect" ng-model="ngModel">',
                '<option ng-repeat="country in ctrl.countries" ng-selected="ctrl.countryFromIP == country.name" value={{country.name}}>',
                    '{{country.name}}',
                '</option>',
            '</select>',
        ].join('')
    }
})
```

What makes things more weird is that in a **simpler version** of the directive that doesn't use at all the preselect, the `ng-model` will be set.

It's kinda hard to understand without an example, so here's a Plunkr!
http://plnkr.co/edit/e1HPgGQlne7Q4TcNJ9XT?p=preview

Comment: to minimize the chances that this question will be downvoted/voted for closure as off topic, you should include the relevant code illustrating the problem in the question body.  Link only code can change over time, making the question or potential answers less useful to others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use ngOptions instead of ngRepeat. I forked [dave's plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZkUzxytieaGIKwF57dav?p=preview) and adjusted it a bit. Your template with and without preselection will look like this:

```
'<select ng-model="ngModel" ng-options="country.name as country.name for country in ctrl.countries"></select>'
```

I did the pre-selection in the countries controller instead of the view/template, just like in angular's documentation for [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).

```
$scope.ngModel = $scope.preselect ? $scope.ngModel = vm.countries[3].name : "";
```

(if preselect equals true then set default for ngModel, else set empty string - javascript ternary operator.)

Answer (score 2):

You should never use `ng-repeat` on `<option>`, instead use `ng-options` on the `<select>`:

```
  <select ng-model="ngModel" ng-options="country.name as country.name for country in ctrl.countries"></select>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ADTPOIKZnnt14lVcr8TN?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for the swift reply, but I'm afraid your code example with the ng-options doesn't work.